# UITableview not loaded data on 3rd time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

Don't know what to do with it. but i loaded data and load table when data is loaded,

```
[manager POST:path parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    arryGlobal = [NSMutableArray new];
    [arryGlobal addObject:responseObject];

    if([[[[arryGlobal valueForKey:@"Success"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"]){

        arryGlobal = [[arryGlobal valueForKey:@"Result"] objectAtIndex:0];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tblMainCategory reloadData];
        });
    }
    else if([[[[arryGlobal valueForKey:@"Success"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"0"]){

    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    //here is place for code executed in error case
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error while sending"
                                                        message:@"Sorry, try again."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

It works perfectly two times, but when i go for 3rd time call this webservice it load data, get data, table successfully reloaded, but it not change content in table, it appear as it is in 2nd time.

SO what happens there ?? When I scroll table, then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` array that i use to pass in table is contain data of 2nd time called Webservice.

**EDIT:**

i added this table view VievController in other view like :

```
MainCategory *objMain = [[MainCategory alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainCategory" bundle:nil];
[objMain LoadData:tag];
objMain.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bgViewCat.frame.size.width, self.bgViewCat.frame.size.height);
[self.bgViewCat insertSubview:objMain.view atIndex:1];
[self addChildViewController:objMain];
[objMain didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: You create a new array, add the response object to it and then if something in the response object matches something you then replace the array?  That is ugly.

Comment: what is best practice there to do ?

Comment: @DxAndroid, please update your code structure, it can be crash at any time if there'll be change in response.

Comment: Are you sure the data received on the 3rd attempt is different from the data received from the 2nd attempt?
Also try disabling the cache. Maybe that's what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    if([[[[arryGlobal valueForKey:@"Success"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    [arryGlobal removeAllObjects];
    arryGlobal=[NSarray alloc]init];
    arryGlobal = [[arryGlobal valueForKey:@"Result"] objectAtIndex:0];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tblMainCategory reloadData];
    });
}
```

Comment: and removing all object from arryGlobal, it crash on 3rd line because there's no data in it.

Comment: if (!(arryGlobal == nil || [arryGlobal count] == 0))  {   [arryGlobal removeAllObjects];  }

Answer (score 0):

the block:success() already run in main queue;you needn't use  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue();
and arryGlobal is a kind of NSMutableArray;why you use the function called "thevalueforKey:" to get the value ?
I think maybe you should print the responseObject to check your data

Comment: P.S  is arryGlobal  global variable？

Comment: without dispatch_get_main_queue also not working .. and yes it is Global var.

Comment: what did you get by the function [arryGlobal valueForKey:@"Success"] ?

Comment: __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
    [manager POST:path parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if([[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"Success"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            arryGlobal = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"Result"] objectAtIndex:0];
                [weakself.tblMainCategory reloadData];
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

Comment: try this     <pre> <code>     __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
    [manager POST:path parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if([[[[responseObject valueForKey:@"Success"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            arryGlobal = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"Result"] objectAtIndex:0];
            [weakself.tblMainCategory reloadData];
        }
        
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];</code>

Answer (score 0):

ok so ther's error on :

```
[self.bgViewCat insertSubview:objMain.view atIndex:1];
```

Instead of this I use this and everything is fine, don't know why?:

```
[self.bgViewCat addSubview:objMain.view];
```